# Google form file upload: get filename instead of link to file

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a simple google form which has a file upload option. The uploaded files are saved in my drive folder. I then have a simple script which executes on form submit to save the form values (upload filename, name and email) to a text file. Here's my app script to do that:

```
function onSubmit(e)
{
  var file = e.values[1]; // getting the link instead of the filename 
  var name = e.values[2];
  var email = e.values[3];

  var folderId = "0B6de05UZOb0y1ck4tV3BPWldpMU14SGZncnlHa0tzTXVoZFk";

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  var content = file + "\n" + name + "\n" + email + "\n"

  var file = folder.createFile('My File.txt', content, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);  
}
```

Here's what the output file `My File.txt` looks like:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bVbNAnES33oY4gx8npdp51ZSMekQalk
My Name
my@email.com
```

My question is - instead of a link to the uploaded file, I'd like to have the actual filename. Is there a way I can get the filename from the form responses parameter `e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the file ID you can get the name of the file using the getName() method.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getname)

**Example**

```
function driveFile(){

  //e.values[1] is apparently the file URL 
  var url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bVbNAnES33oY4gx8npdp51ZSMekQalk"
  var id = url.split("=")[1];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var fileName = file.getName();

}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. I was trying to find a function to get the file id from the url but couldn't find one