# How to rename a file on upload using submission strings in google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

This is for a basic google form recording expenses for non-profit housing. Fields of form and goals are listed below. I'm trying to make it so that on submission, uploaded files are renamed using fields from the form itself. The fields that I would like to use are a datepicker, two string dropdowns, and a short answer consisting of numbers. As it is, google renames files by appending "- uploader name" at the end. I would also like to remove that.

I was able to find some answers that would retroactively rename all uploads with manual trigger, but nothing that would do it automatically.

Field details

- submissionDate - a datepicker
- personName - Dropdown of names
- expenseType - Dropdown with strings like food, supplies, and so forth
- expenseAmount - Number, usually in ##.## form.

Target filename: submissionDate(YYYYMMDD)_personName_expenseType_expenseAmount

Thank you so much for the help!

This is incomplete, I don't know the correct way of getting fields

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
    // returns the total number of form submissions
    var length=form.getResponses().length;
    //replace QUESTION NUMBER through the index of the question prompting the file upload - keep in mind that the first question has the index 0
    var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[QUESTION NUMBER].getResponse();
    //getResponses()[length-1] retrieves the last form response, accounting for the fact that the first index is zero and hte last length-1
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    // store filename in variable
    name = file.getName();
    //Removes the built in Name added by google
    var originalname = name.split(' - ')[0]
    // !! Missing, get responses from specific fields, including converting date picker into yyyymmdd format
    var newname = datefield+namefield+typefield+originalname
    file.setName(name);
}
```

[example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CDi3kWG1Z7xPB8B1Ej_4Il3RCMl5jl8kp7zVa7PF05E/edit#gid=1730946666) added two columns showing original filename and what I would want it renamed to, this doesn't have to show on the sheet, just renamed in google drive.

**Here's the solution based on the answer by @Tedinoz below, with some changes to fix filename extensions and such.**

```
function updateFileName(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var values = e.values
  //get the file details
  var fileURL = values[5]
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the file url = "+fileURL)
  var id = fileURL.split("=")[1]
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the file ID = "+id)
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  var uploadFileName = file.getName()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the existing file name = "+uploadFileName)
  var extension = uploadFileName.split('.').pop();

  // get the file name variables
  var submittedDate = values[2].toString()
  var yyyy = submittedDate.split("/")[2]
  var mm = submittedDate.split("/")[0]
  // ensure leading zero
  if (mm.length == 1){
    mm = "0"+mm 
  } 
  var dd = submittedDate.split("/")[1]
  // ensure leading zero
  if (dd.length == 1){
    dd = "0"+dd 
  } 
  var personName = values[1]
  var expenseType = values[3]
  var expenseAmount = values[6]

  //String replacements for filename friendly text
  var expenseAmount = expenseAmount.replace('.', 'd').replace(',', 'd').replace('$', '');
  var expenseType = expenseType.replace('&','And').replace(' ','');
  
  var newName = yyyy+mm+dd+"_"+personName+"_"+expenseType+"_"+expenseAmount+"."+extension
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the new name = "+newName)

  // save the new file name
  file.setName(newName)

  // include this lines if you want to confirm the file name chnage
  
  var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  var revisedFileName = file.getName()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the updated file name = "+revisedFileName)
  
}
```

You have to install an on form submit trigger like so using the left panel of the editor
[on form submit trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjP7u.png)

Comment: Here are a few thoughts:. If you have a linked spreadsheet, then [Google form file upload: get filename instead of link to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58428083/1330560) is all you need. If you don't have a spreadsheet containing the responses, then then the answer by @Tanaike answer in  [How can I get the responses directly form a Google Form and send then to a new spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69564676/1330560) is a excellent. And of course, you can combine the two answers to convert an ID to and file name.

Comment: You want to rename `automatically.` but there are three fields (datapicker, name, and Expense) that must be **manually** chosen before a file can be renamed. I suggest export the form submissions to a sheet, create adjacent columns for the manual dropdowns and two extra columns of "checkboxes". Then you can make the manual selections, confirm the new file name, check the first box to change the name. Then either by batch or `onedit` trigger, run a script to change the file name of the checked rows and update the second checkbox to indicate completion. Can you manage that?

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we may further help you?

Comment: @Tedinoz maybe there was confusion. I'm not trying to get the filename, I'm trying to make it based on their form entry. Users will choose/enter the fields, choose a file to upload, and hit submit. I want the file to be renamed, on submission, using the fields they chose/entered.

Comment: @PatrickdC I made a submission, copied the sheet, and shared it above. I also added two columns to show what an example filename/rename would be.

Comment: The `onFormSubmit` trigger (both Form and Sheet) is run **when a user responds to a form**. So renaming must be done AFTER submission. Add Form questions for "Date", "Person" :and "Expense" so these values are accessible as Event Objects The sheets [Event Objects ](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) are easy to access. . So, I'd use a script bound to the linked sheet, triggered by 'onFormSubmit', and accessing Event Objects.

Comment: I'll try to replicate this on my side. However, I do agree with @Tedinoz that the renaming can only be done after submission and that a bound script must be used on the forms repository sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the file name of a file uploaded from a Google Form.

Some notable aspects of the following answer are:

- based on a script bound to a spreadsheet linked to the form.
- function is triggered by an installable event trigger: `onFormSubmit`
- function uses Event Objects to access the form response items.

---

```
function updateFileName(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var values = e.values
  //get the file details
  var fileURL = values[5]
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the file url = "+fileURL)
  var id = fileURL.split("=")[1]
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the file ID = "+id)
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  var uploadFileName = file.getName()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the existing file name = "+uploadFileName)

  // get the file name variables
  var submittedDate = values[2].toString()
  var yyyy = submittedDate.split("/")[2]
  var mm = submittedDate.split("/")[0]
  // ensure leading zero
  if (mm.length == 1){
    mm = "0"+mm 
  } 
  var dd = submittedDate.split("/")[1]
  // ensure leading zero
  if (dd.length == 1){
    dd = "0"+dd 
  } 
  var personName = values[1]
  var expenseType = values[3]
  var expenseAmount = values[6]
  var newName = yyyy+mm+dd+"_"+personName+"_"+expenseType+"_"+expenseAmount
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the new name = "+newName)

  // save the new file name
  file.setName(newName)

  // include this lines if you want to confirm the file name chnage
  
  var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  var revisedFileName = file.getName()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the updated file name = "+revisedFileName)
  
}
```

---

---

**SAMPLE - Linked Sheet**

[image: link]

---

**SAMPLE - Executions Log**

[image: log]

Comment: Thank you so much. There was some issues, like losing the file extension, but I was able to fix that. I also added some string sanitization, replacing dots or dollar signs in amounts (in case someone enters that).

Comment: Those are good points. They should also serve as a future reminder to include as much detail as possible in the question/expected outcome. BTW, if this answer was helpful, then you might consider accepting it.

Comment: I already accepted the answer yesterday before I left the comment. Thanks once again